# Javascript IE8: All buttons within form trigger submission

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I'm facing a problem which I yet haven't found a solution for.

I have a form with two types of buttons inside: one `<button type="submit">`, and one plain `<button>`. I have a *submit* event on the form, which should only be triggered by the submit button. Then I have another event bound to the plain button, which actually has nothing to do with the submission of the form; It's a delete button. Even though I return false and prevent the default behavior of that button it still triggers the form submission.

The same problem occurs with all non-submit buttons within forms. If I remove the *submit* event on the form it works great. It seems to override all other events bound to the buttons inside.

Is there anyway of fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying setting type="button" on the buttons you don't want to submit the form. By default I believe IE8 will try and submit the form for all buttons, not just those where type="submit".

Also how are you overriding the default button behaviour?

It should be in the onclick event ie onclick="return doSomething();"